# time between two dates? number as year

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
CollegeData<-structure(list(PUBID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), CVC_BA_DEGREE = structure(c(2003.41666666667, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2003.5, 2005.41666666667, 2004.41666666667, NA, 
NA), class = "yearmon"), FirstYear4C = c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2005, 
2000, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2001, 2002)), .Names = c("PUBID", "CVC_BA_DEGREE", 
"FirstYear4C"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a new column,

```
CollegeData$TTD=CollegeData$CVC_BA_DEGREE-CollegeData$FirstYear4C
```

where the first element is June 2003-1999 = 4 years, and the second is NA - 2000=NA

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the example you provded?

Comment: How about `floor`?  as in:  `floor(CollegeData$CVC_BA_DEGREE - CollegeData$FirstYear4C)`

Comment: I'm not sure. For the first observation I get June 4 instead of 4 years. I probably need to convert FirstYear4C from numeric to date. But not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as you have  CVC_BA_DEGREE  as yearmon but FirstYear4C as numeric, you need to make them comparable before subtracting them.

```
CollegeData$TTD=CollegeData$CVC_BA_DEGREE-CollegeData$FirstYear4C
# won't make sense ... unless you use it without zoo package where yearmon is defined

CollegeData$TTD=as.numeric(CollegeData$CVC_BA_DEGREE)-CollegeData$FirstYear4C
CollegeData$TTD=CollegeData$CVC_BA_DEGREE-as.yearmon(CollegeData$FirstYear4C)
# both lead to the same result
```

If you want a "shorter" result i.e 4 instead of 4.41667 then use `trunc` or `round` or `floor`.

**Edit:** You forgot to mention that you're using functions from package `zoo`. If you don't have zoo then yearmon objects will behave like usual numbers - and you can use functions like floor or trunc with them.

Answer (score 1):

As I interpret this question you want a whole number for the year? 
I would complete this as:

`CollegeData$TTD=floor(CollegeData$CVC_BA_DEGREE)-CollegeData$FirstYear4C`

Comment: This is not working for me. I Jan 4 for the first observation instead of 4.

Comment: Could you show what your output looks like?